# Need Icon beside navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I need help in this code to put Icon beside the navbar from the first word Dashboard without spacing using Bootstrap only,

Note: I used options, like `offset-5` and `ms-5` but they were not what I needed,

```html
<div id="navbarcollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    
  <a href="Index.html" class="navbar-brand p-0">
    <img src="Images/icons-internet.png" class="w-50 h-50 " />
  </a>
    
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="Index.html">DashBoard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="Posts.html">Posts</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="Categories.html">Categories</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="Users.html">Users</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this ...

```
<img src="Images/icons-internet.png" class="col-8 offset-4 " />
```

will contain an image that will be used as the navbar brand. The image will be 8 columns wide and will be offset by 4 columns to the right.

you can change the spacing by (offset),

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Display Flex and you don't want to use options like offset-5 and ms-5 then you can use gap-5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).